# Angular js remove leading & trailing spaces from the input textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

See this Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/YAQooPn0UERDI5UEoQ23?p=preview

Type text as "_______what___ever_____" 
 (without quotes & _ represents spaces.)

Angular is removing spaces (from front & back & not in between) from the model (which is my desired behavior), but my textbox is keeping the spaces.

how can I remove the spaces from the textbox also ? i.e. I want the textbox also to reflect the value in model.

**Edit:** Better explanation of my needs.

**For Eg:** 
If I typed "___What_Ever____" ( without quote & _ is space),

1) my textbox will show me same what i have typed i.e. "___What_Ever____"

2) while my model will show me "What Ever".

I want my textbox's value also to be as "What Ever".

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@1.9.0" data-semver="1.9.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.7" data-semver="1.0.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="modelVal">
    <br>
    model value is "{{modelVal}}"
  </body>

</html>
```

**JS :**

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.modelVal="";

  })
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to remove leading and trailing spaces as the user is typing.

Comment: @camden_kid i am fine even if it happens on a blur or some other event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would this work? - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/miKctaHeyJHADI3FQZxd?p=preview)

`ng-blur` doesn't work with your Plunker because the version of AngularJS you are loading (1.0.7) is quite old. I replaced it with the latest version (1.5.6). I also use `ng-trim="false"` to get the correct text input by the user.

Markup

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="modelVal" ng-change="change()" ng-blur="blur()" ng-trim="false">
    <br>
    model value is "{{newModelVal}}"
</body>
```

JS

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.modelVal="";
    $scope.change = function () {
      $scope.newModelVal = $scope.modelVal;
    }
    $scope.blur = function () {
      $scope.modelVal = $scope.newModelVal.trim();
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this,

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <input type="text" ng-change="modelVal = modelVal.split(' ').join('')" ng-model="modelVal">
 <br>
  model value is "{{modelVal}}"
</body>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/sleXyL2RaL0k4UISQqDS?p=preview)**

**EDIT:**

You can use [**ngTrim**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D) which is provided by Angular itself

```
 <input type="text" ng-trim="true" ng-model="modelVal">
 <br> model value is "{{modelVal}}"
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sleXyL2RaL0k4UISQqDS?p=preview)

Comment: This will remove spaces in between words also.

Comment: this is what you asked in question

Comment: sorry for confusion. i only want to remove leading(from the start) & trailing (from the end) spaces.

Comment: `ng-trim` works with recent versions of Angular, the plunker uses the ancient 1.0.7... Change it to 1.5.x and it works.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos yes i changed it, but still the textbox is not updated. the model value does show the spaces. I want to change the value in textbox also along with the model value.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanSayed check this demo http://plnkr.co/edit/sleXyL2RaL0k4UISQqDS?p=preview